# Datatable row : manually update field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable. I get a set of selected rows.
When i loop through, and update the value of a field remark,
I can't do it.

how do i manually update the value of a specific field in a row?

```
var table = $('#bankReconDataListing').DataTable();
$.map(table.rows('.selectedrow').data(), function (item) {
    item.remarks = 'updated values';
    console.log('-----------------1>',item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table id="bankReconDataListing">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>head</td>
                <td>gender</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>one</td><td>boy</td></tr>
            <tr class="selectedrow"><td>two</td><td>boys</td></tr>
            <tr><td>three</td>
            <td>boys</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



    var table = $('#bankReconDataListing').DataTable();
    var temp = table.row(2).data();
    alert("value before update = " + temp[0]);
    temp[0] = "six";
    table.row(2).data(temp).draw();
    alert("value after update = " + temp[0]);
```